# How to simplify transforming entity framework entities to DTOs

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I map to a data transformation object when retrieving items from an ASP.NET Web API like so for a list:

```
public async Task<IList<PromotionDTO>> GetPromotionsList()
{
    return await _context.Promotions
    .Select(p => new PromotionDTO
    {
        PromotionId = p.PromotionId,
        Is_Active = p.Is_Active,
        Created = p.Created,
        Title = p.Title,
        BusinessName = p.BusinessName,
    })
    .Where(x => x.Is_Active)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
    .ToListAsync();
}
```

And like this for getting a single record:

```
public async Task<PromotionDTO> GetPromotion(int id)
{
    return await _context.Promotions
    .Select(p => new PromotionDTO
    {
        PromotionId = p.PromotionId,
        Is_Active = p.Is_Active,
        Created = p.Created,
        Title = p.Title,
        BusinessName = p.BusinessName,
    })
    .Where(x => x.Is_Active && x.PromotionId == id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

I'm new to DTO's and I find that I'm using the same DTO transformation code at many places, and was wondering how I can simplify my code to only do this once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it may be enough to map like you've stated, but when your project starts to grow it will just complicated things and cause additional work.

I suggest that you use some kind of mapping library like AutoMapper.
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

```
static MyRepositoryConstructor()
{
    // Define your maps
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<PromotionEntity, PromotionDTO>();
    });
}

public async Task<IList<PromotionDTO>> GetPromotionsList()
{
    return Mapper.Map<IList<PromotionDTO>>(await _context.Promotions
        .Where(x => x.Is_Active)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
        .ToListAsync()
    );
}

public async Task<PromotionDTO> GetPromotion(int id)
{

    return Mapper.Map<PromotionDTO>(await _context.Promotions
        .Where(x => x.Is_Active && x.PromotionId == id)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a method which returns an [IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use that in each

```
Private IQueryable<PromotionDTO> Query()
{
    return _context.Promotions
    .Select(p => new PromotionDTO
    {
        PromotionId = p.PromotionId,
        Is_Active = p.Is_Active,
        Created = p.Created,
        Title = p.Title,
        BusinessName = p.BusinessName,
    });
}

public async Task<IList<PromotionDTO>> GetPromotionsList()
{
    return await Query()
    .Where(x => x.Is_Active)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
    .ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<PromotionDTO> GetPromotion(int id)
{

    return await Query()
    .Where(x => x.Is_Active && x.PromotionId == id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: The only problem here is that the private function is not async so the other functions error out

Comment: This would be much better as an extension method